# In order to guarantee type-safety, is the "as const" assertion the only solution here?

Tags: typescript

I have the following `objectify` implementation:

```
type MappedObject<T extends readonly string[]> = {
  [key in T[number]]: number;
};

function objectify<T extends readonly string[]>(array: T): MappedObject<T> {
  return array.reduce(
    (acc, term, index) => ({ ...acc, [term]: index }),
    {}
  ) as MappedObject<T>;
}
```

<sup>[Playground link.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?removeComments=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmSATA8gIwFYQMbADwAqUEAHsBAHZIDOUAThHEgPYUA2IU1wdAlhQHMA2gF0AfFAC8UAN4AoKFCEBrCJ35QCQigFcAtmgh0RIgFxRdBowG45AX1tyAZjoq5erKM0w5gvJyCExGSUNPSMLOyc3HyComIAFHB0dHAg5gQAlObwiBCoPriEEvKKDMA6dBRQyakgAHQMSDrYEAkKilBJ2NgANFDkdHr9-EikmVISCTJQ9XNwPf1Cg3pmUKOkUHaZvR2KMnYdE3C0ucjoWEUEYraHcvfYrNxccE4QF1JehX4BCUIA5HB-v1-mhgVB-th-iIarRHhRuJlrFAAPQoqAAOWYflaAwAFtAAAYnKDw7iE2HUIx%20Vj1OTUV7vTD1OC2BlvC71NBsxmc7A8jnMpDItFQACiKWYdAAhLBOI8xutaOyIPUoKZMvcHk9gFBXCqPtJvJcfiA-oDwaDLVCREjUeisVA9FKiSSycAKScqXQaRQ6freczWXIA4KMFzbKGmeH%20SGEYHw8L7ZjmMRJXRqLKYPLmIreLQjHQpVAwEWKKr1QkgA)</sup>

With that implementation, when I call `objectify` asserting the first passed argument with `as const`, it returns a *type-safe* object, as you can see in the following example:

```
const obj = objectify(['a', 'b', 'c'] as const); // Notice the `as const` assertion.

obj.a;
obj.b;
obj.c;
obj.d; // Error! My code is safe. :)
```

<sup>[Example of this **"safe"** behavior in the playground.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?removeComments=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmSATA8gIwFYQMbADwAqUEAHsBAHZIDOUAThHEgPYUA2IU1wdAlhQHMA2gF0AfFAC8UAN4AoKFCEBrCJ35QCQigFcAtmgh0RIgFxRdBowG45AX1tyAZjoq5erKM0w5gvJyCExGSUNPSMLOyc3HyComIAFHB0dHAg5gQAlObwiBCoPriEEvKKDMA6dBRQyakgAHQMSDrYEAkKilBJ2NgANFDkdHr9-EikmVISCTJQ9XNwPf1Cg3pmUKOkUHaZvR2KMnYdE3C0ucjoWEUEYraHctis3FxwThAXUl6FfgEJQgDkcD+-T+aCBUD+2D+IhqtAeFG4mWsUAA9MioAA5Zh+VoDAAW0AABicoHDuASYdQjH5WPU5NQXm9MPU4LZ6a8LvU0KyGRzsNz2UykEjUVAAKIpZh0ACEsE4DzG61obIg9SgpkyQA)</sup>

Sadly, however, when I remove that `as const` assertion, that type-safety goes away, which turns my code error-prone. Because of that "unsafe" returned type, I can even access properties that don't even exist in the returned object, as exemplified (`obj.d`) in the last line of the following example:

```
const obj = objectify(['a', 'b', 'c']); // No more `as const` assertion.

obj.a;
obj.b;
obj.c;
obj.d; // No errors! My code is error prone. :(
```

<sup>[Example of this **"unsafe"** behavior in the playground.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?removeComments=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmSATA8gIwFYQMbADwAqUEAHsBAHZIDOUAThHEgPYUA2IU1wdAlhQHMA2gF0AfFAC8UAN4AoKFCEBrCJ35QCQigFcAtmgh0RIgFxRdBowG45AX1tyAZjoq5erKM0w5gvJyCExGSUNPSMLOyc3HyComIAFHB0dHAg5gQAlObwiBCoPriEEvKKDMA6dBRQyakgAHQMSDrYEAkKilBJ2NgANFDkdHr9-EikmVISCTJQ9XNwPf1Cg3pmUKOkUHaZvR2KMnYdE3C0ucjoWEUEYraHctis3FCu1HBOEBdSXoV+AQlCAHI4AD+gC0CCoADsACRJlrFAAPQIqAAOWYUD0zAYUAABicoA8KNwcTVqNQjH5WPU5C83h9MPU4LZae8LvU0MyiXS2dhOa9WQykPCkaj0UY6FjqABCWCcB5jda0cVYqBgCUUCD1KCmBJAA)</sup>

---

**The question is:** Is using the `as const` assertion the only way to guarantee that type-safety? **There is another way of achieve this same "safe" behavior?**

My goal is to fully guarantee the code safety in the function implementation, avoiding any assertion when I invoke the function. I want to make the following code safe by only changing the function implementation, and not its calls.

```
// What I can do:
const obj = objectify(['a', 'b', 'c'] as const);

// What I want to be able to do:
const obj = objectify(['a', 'b', 'c']);

///// `obj` would be "safe" here.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel your pain here.  Ideally there would be a feature which allows you to annotate a function so that it treats certain arguments [`as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#const-assertions) without requiring the caller to do it.  I've asked for this in [microsoft/TypeScript#30680](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680); if you want to see this happen, you might want to go there and give it a , but for now it's not a feature.

Luckily there *are* ways to write function signatures that give the compiler hints to guide inference like this; it's just that they are hard to comprehend and seem like bizarre magic instead of straightforward communication of the developer's intent.

In the specific case of inferring [string literal types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types), one way to get this to happen is to use a type parameter constrained to `string` (i.e., `S extends string`) instead of `string` itself (see [microsoft/TypeScript#10676](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676)):

```
function objectify<T extends readonly S[], S extends string>(array: T): MappedObject<T> {
  return array.reduce(
    (acc, term, index) => ({ ...acc, [term]: index }),
    {}
  ) as MappedObject<T>;
}
```

This looks kind of useless, especially because `S` will likely be inferred as `string`.  But crucially, this causes the type of `T` to be inferred as `Array<"a" | "b" | "c">` instead of `Array<string>`:

```
const stillSafeObj = objectify(['a', 'b', 'c']); // No more `as const` assertion.
stillSafeObj.a;
stillSafeObj.b;
stillSafeObj.c;
stillSafeObj.d; // Error! My code is safe. :)
```

It works.  Hooray for bizarre magic!! ‍♂️✨

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?removeComments=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmSATA8gIwFYQMbADwAqUEAHsBAHZIDOUAThHEgPYUA2IU1wdAlhQHMA2gF0AfFAC8UAN4AoKFCEBrCJ35QCQigFcAtmgh0RIgFxRdBowG45AX1tyAZjoq5erKM0w5gvJyCExGSUNPSMLOycAMqiADRQ0cHkVLTcfIJiABRwdHRwIOYEAJTm8IgQqD64hBLyigzAOnQUULn5IAB0DEg62BBZCopQOdjYCeR0egn8SKTFUhJZMlCda3BjCUKTemZQs6RQdsVxQ4oydkMLcLTlyOhYNQRitpdyctis3FxwThAPUi81T8ASyQgA5HBwQlwWhoVBwdhwSI2rRPhRuMVrFAAPQ4qAAOWYfn6UGAAAtoAADG5QdHcKmo6hGPysTpyai-f6YTpwWycv4PTpoflcoXYUWCnlIbF4qAAUTyzDoAEJYJxPnN9mkuZ0oKZiu93vTgFw-Gw2NExZhAd5HiCQGDIfDYS6kSIsbj8USoHpldTaSbGTdmXRWRR2dxeBarVKMLz+ebLdb4yKOUnY9z4xL09Hk3HOjKvQqlar1XTmFreDq-nqDUA)